# Optimise query to remove “Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort”

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I have 2 SQL query that i'm trying to optimise to remove "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort".

first query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.pseudo , M.id as id , CM.send FROM `chat_messages` CM
inner JOIN `uniic_member` M 
ON ((CM.`receiver_id` = 22141 AND M.id=CM.sender_id and CM.`status` != 2)
OR (CM.`sender_id` = 22141 AND M.id=CM.receiver_id AND CM.`status` != 1))
GROUP BY pseudo ORDER BY send DESC;
```

second query :

```
SELECT e.*, p.filename AS photo, m.pseudo AS pseudo, m.gender AS gender 
FROM uniic_mailbox AS e 
 LEFT JOIN uniic_member AS m ON m.id = e.sender_id LEFT JOIN uniic_photos AS p 
     ON (m.id = p.member_id AND p.main_photo = 1) WHERE e.status IN (0,1) 
     AND e.member_id = 2248 AND e.sender_id 
     NOT IN (SELECT ban_id FROM uniic_blacklist WHERE member_id = 2248) 
     AND e.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM uniic_mailbox 
     WHERE status IN (0,1) AND member_id = 2248 AND sender_id = e.sender_id LIMIT 1) 
     GROUP BY e.id ORDER BY e.created_at DESC LIMIT 0 , 11;
```

Please tell me is there any way to fix "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" and improve perfomance of this query?

Comment: remove the `order by` to remote the filesort bit.

Comment: Removing the somewhat-misnamed "filesort" isn't possible with a query that's joined then ordered like these. Read this. http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=24

Comment: See [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44627/1064). Also NOT IN isn't sargable.